# GnuTLS error -15 on vsftpd

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, ftps, vsftpd

**I am using ubuntu server with vsftpd service, connecting over SSL. When connecting using Filezilla randomly getting below error.**

```
Error:    GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:    GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

It will be okay after restarting vsftpd service and will again showing after some days. tried reinstalling vsftpd service and regenerated certificate.

**Here is my /etc/vsftpd.conf`**

```
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key  
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem  
ssl_ciphers=HIGH  
pasv_enable=YES  
pasv_max_port=12110  
pasv_min_port=12099  
port_enable=YES  
pasv_address=<ip>  
ssl_enable=YES  
allow_anon_ssl=NO  
force_local_data_ssl=YES  
force_local_logins_ssl=YES  
ssl_tlsv1=NO  
ssl_sslv2=NO  
ssl_sslv3=NO  
require_ssl_reuse=NO  
allow_writeable_chroot=YES  
pasv_promiscuous=YES
```

I have tried both active and passive mode and using ec2 instance and ports are opened on security groups. Tried same time different ISP ips and different location( not a local firewall issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the line seccomp_sandbox=NO on /etc/vsftpd.conf file solved my issue.